# Differential Equation & MacLaurin Series for Newton’s Second Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, calculus, approximations, differential-equations

I am currently working with a differential equation, where I think I need to take the derivative of $ma$ (corrected as per comment). I am trying to write $F = ma$ as a MacLaurin series and eventually set it in terms of $m\ddot x(t)$. The problem is that I am not sure if I should write my MacLaurin series in terms of $x$ also or use a. Also, I am not very sure if you take the derivative of $a$ if you would have to use Chain Rule or if you could simply take the third derivative of position. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I am really confused because if you plug in x=0 to solve for the constants, you get just zero for everything! And that can’t be right.

Comment: Can you post the exact problem, you are talking about?

Comment: For the derivative of a^2 you certainly need to use chain rule the third derivative of position wouldn't work. Apart from that I am not very familiar with the MacLaurin series (haven't studied that yet) so I can't help on that

Comment: Here is the start of the question: (a) Using Newton’s second law, write a differential equation for the position x(t) of an object experiencing a Force F(x). (b) Any oscillator moves back and forth across some equilibrium point. For simplicity you can always define that equilibrium point to be at x=0, in which case it is natural to expand F(x) in a MacLaurin series. Write a second-order MacLaurin series for F(x) and plug this into the equation you wrote down in part (a). The result should be a diff. eq. with x”(t) on the left and three terms on the right. Please no answer but hint(s) -thanks!

Comment: $F=ma^2$ cannot be correct because it is dimensionally inconsistent. Therefore you have made a mistake somewhere in getting to this equation. Checking dimensions is a very useful way to find mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was going back and forth between a and a”(t), and got mixed up late at night! Thank you very much. I will look at it again. However, I do still experience the same problem of everything going to zero.

Comment: You are being asked to write the McLaurin expansion of $F(x)$, so not that of 
$
ma= \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}.
$

Comment: But aren’t they the same thing? Part a says to use Newton’s second law, which is F(x)=m*a(t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the problem statement, you want to start with Newton's 2nd law,

> $F$ = ma

for some general Force $F$. Let's suppose we're talking about the 1-dimensional displacement $x$ of a particle with mass $m$ at time $t$.

Writing $F(x)$ means

> $F(x) = ma = m*\left(\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}\right)$.

which we shall call Eq. (1). It seems you've gotten that far on your own.

Now, write down the Taylor series (it's a "[Maclaurin series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html)" since the origin of the particle's displacement is zero, i.e. the series is expanded about zero) for a function $F(x)$. Don't write terms higher than the "second-order" derivative. Call this Eq. (2).

Now, set Eq.'s (1) and (2) equal to each other (i.e. substitute in for $F(x)$) and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks very much! This helped a lot!

Comment: @Yelena My pleasure! If you've solved your problem, please accept my answer as the "correct" one. But you can still ask questions here after doing so. Thanks!